# Actually working sample code or guide with actual working code for 1. authenticating a C# .net core console app and 2. calling? the web api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

SDK sample code projects use deprecated and removed methods, articles and guides on official documentation don't have standalone working examples, just snippets of the sample code projects. In other words, it seems that there is actually no working way to use the Graph API programmatically.

Is anyone actually using Microsoft Graph successfully in their own solutions? I have yet to find any code that actually successfully 1. builds and 2. authenticates. Is anyone at Microsoft actually working on this?

all of the examples, samples, and guides on microsoft graph official site

attempt to build any sample code from microsoft graph official site. seriously

missing method definitions
calling deprecated methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please checkout these GitHub samples that should help you get started.

- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample
- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/dotnetcore-console-sample

They offer great examples and instructions. And you could always raise an issue against the specific repositories in case you find something off.